# What word can be used to describe a process that has not exited when it should have and is using 100% cpu

Tags: linux, process

I'm looking for some terminology that may be specific to linux, or it may not.

I don't think zombie process is correct. Maybe the process is hanging?

I would like to be able to say "process 1234 is [some word], i shall kill it". Or something similar

**Edit:**
the process is using 100% cpu according to the `top` command.

**Edit 2:**
As it turns out. The process was still running. It had just gone to the back ground, and was in a loop expecting user input, hence the high cpu usage.

Comment: The process "diverges" or is "divergent"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_%28computer_science%29

Comment: any comment for the down vote? is this not the correct place for this question?

Comment: @Alex I think divergent is more of a mathematical term, that maybe isn't quite appropriate.